# query doesn't work for half-words in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have written this query in rails but it only give me documents when I write the whole word for example when I write `Statement` it gives me all the docs which have the word Statement but if I write `Stat` it doesn't give me any document. So the query is word-sensitive and I worked to make it non word-sensitive but somehow doesn't work and idk why.

```
def set_query
  @query = params[:query]
end


def set_documents
  @documents = @folder ? @folder.documents : current_user.documents
  @documents = (params[:query] ? @documents.where(
      :$text => {:$search => { name: (/.*(#{@query})+.*/i)}.to_s}
  ) : @documents).page(params[:page])
end
```

any help would be appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using case insensitive regex search.

```
def set_documents
  @documents = @folder ? @folder.documents : current_user.documents
  @documents = (params[:query] ? @documents.where(
      {'name': {'$regex': @query, '$options': i}}).page(params[:page])
end
```

Comment: I had to change it slightly to not get an error like this:   
`def set_documents
    @documents = @folder ? @folder.documents : current_user.documents
    @documents = (params[:query] ? @documents.where(
        {'name': {'$regex': @query, '$options': i}}) : @documents).page(params[:page])
  end` 
and then I get `undefined local variable or method 'i' for #<UserDocumentsController:0x00...`

Comment: try using in inverted comma `'i'`

Comment: did that but it's not even case insensitive anymore, the problem lies that we are not really searching the field itself, but the index, therefore my query isn't working properly I guess.